# Getting error on sorting Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> sort(Dictionary<string,                                       Dictionary<string, string>> prods)
    {
        int a, b;
         var sortedDict =new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
         sortedDict = from entry in prods orderby entry.Value["SortOrder"] ascending select entry;

        return sortedDict;
    }
```

Error:

> Error 4   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable>>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Could you show use `Prods` class?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A dictionary is not ordered. Use a plain collection type (IEnumerable, List, array, ...) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ToDictionary` to create a dictionary - but that won't actually achieve what you want.

A `Dictionary<,>` simply *isn't* a sorted data structure. The ordering should not be relied on. Even though the current implementation *may* return entries in the order they were added, that's an implementation detail:

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

You might want to look at [`SortedDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but given that the sort order appears to depend on the *value* rather than the key, it may well not be feasible.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could potentially just declare that you return an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`